# Coinbase show's that ETH been withdraw but showing zero value and where i am sending it they haven't receive any funds either

Tags: etherscan, coinbase

Coinbase show's that ETH been withdraw but showing zero value and where i am sending it they haven't receive any funds either.

Can someone help me to explain it.

[image]

Comment: The eth is at the address on chain, who are you sending it to? If it isn't your address they may not be an honest person.

Answer (score 1):

It is there: [image]

https://etherscan.io/address/0x59ba65a526eff767abac9d528bc96d9041b51003

Check the address in a block explorer

[image]